# SSSD with LDAP users not able to resolve their own uid/gid names and others

Tags: ldap, sssd, uid

I have a machine setup to authenticate users with an LDAP directory using sssd+nss+pam.

At the current state any user in the directory is able to login by ssh, or  with `su` in between user accounts, but it seems they are not able to retrieve their own `uid` and `gid` neither the ones from the rest of users.

Only root is able to resolve everything without issues, i guess this might come from a sssd.conf misconfiguration but i can't find out what could be causing this.

Behaviour observed as root:

```
[root@frontend ~]# ll /home/
total 0
drwx------. 2 chao    staff   83 Oct 25 22:57 chao
drwx------. 2 wshake  staff   99 Oct 26 12:45 wshake
[root@frontend ~]# id wshake
uid=10101(wshake) gid=10001(staff) groups=10001(staff)
[root@frontend ~]# id chao
uid=10103(chao) gid=10001(staff) groups=10001(staff)
[root@frontend ~]# getent passwd wshake
wshake:*:10101:10001:wshake:/home/wshake:/bin/bash
```

I can login with `ssh` or `su` as any of the users but they won't see their uid/gid names themselves with `getent passwd myuid` neither:

```
[root@frontend ~]# su - wshake
Last login: Fri Oct 26 14:08:23 CEST 2018 on pts/1
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID 10101
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 10001
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID 10101
[I have no name!@frontend ~]$ id
uid=10101 gid=10001 groups=10001 context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[I have no name!@frontend ~]$ id wshake
id: wshake: no such user
[I have no name!@frontend ~]$ getent passwd wshake
[I have no name!@frontend ~]$ su chao
Password:
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 10001
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID 10103
[I have no name!@frontend wshake]$ id
uid=10103 gid=10001 groups=10001 context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[I have no name!@frontend wshake]$ getent passwd chao
[I have no name!@frontend wshake]$
```

The /etc/sssd/sssd.config i'm using:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = LDAP

[domain/LDAP]
debug_level = 7
enumerate = True
cache_credentials = false
ldap_schema = rfc2307
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
access_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldaps://frontend
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
ldap_search_base = dc=test,dc=cluster
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=cluster
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = testpass
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/certs/cert.crt

ldap_access_filter = (&(objectclass=posixAccount))
ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://frontend

ldap_user_object_class = posixAccount
ldap_user_name = uid
ldap_user_uid_number = uidNumber
ldap_user_gid_number = gidNumber
ldap_group_name = cn
ldap_group_object_class = posixGroup
ldap_group_gid_number = gidNumber

[nss]
debug_level = 7
override_homedir = /home/%u
override_shell = /bin/bash
```

Anybody has a hint of what to look at?

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong with permissions of the Unix domain socket used sssd listens on.

Comment: Finally found out the issue, it was indeed a permissions thing but with  `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, it was set as `600`, changing to world readable `644` made everything work fine

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is also world readable. How else might I debug this?